# How can i implement the following typescript code better?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, factory

I have following typescript code which implements a request-response flow.

There can be two types of DataRequest - FooDataRequest & BarDataRequest .

There are multiple resolvers  for these request types . FooResolver does Foo specific things and sends back FooDataResponse and BarResolver which does Bar specific things and send back BarDataResponse

```
abstract class DataRequest{
    public type: typeof DataRequest;
    public payload: string;
}
abstract class DataResponse { 
    public data: any;
}

class FooDataRequest extends DataRequest { 
    constructor() { 
        super();
        this.type = FooDataRequest;
        this.payload = "foo request";
    }
}

class BarDataRequest extends DataRequest { 
     constructor() { 
        super();
        this.type = FooDataRequest;
        this.payload = "foo request";
    }
}

class FooDataResponse extends DataResponse { 
    constructor() { 
        super();
        this.data = "foo response";
    }
}
class BarDataResponse extends DataResponse { 
    constructor() { 
        super();
        this.data = "bar response";
    }
}

abstract class DataResolver { 
    abstract resolve(request:DataRequest): DataResponse 
}

class FooViewResolver extends DataResolver { 
    public resolve(reportRequest:FooDataRequest): FooDataResponse { 
        return new FooDataResponse();
    }
}

class BarViewResolver extends DataResolver { 
    public resolve(dashboardRequest:BarDataRequest): BarDataResponse { 
        return new BarDataResponse();
    }
}

class ResolverFactory { 
    public static getResolver(request: DataRequest): DataResolver { 
        //If there is 100 request , then so many if else statement
        //That is not effective
        if (request.type === FooDataRequest) {
            return new FooViewResolver();
       }
        else if (request.type = BarDataRequest) { 
            return new BarViewResolver();
        }
    }
}



const request :DataRequest = new FooDataRequest();
const resolver: DataResolver = ResolverFactory.getResolver(request);
console.log(resolver);
const response: DataResponse = resolver.resolve(request);
console.log(response);
```

What is the best method to implement a resolver factory?  If i have 100 request types then if will have multiple if else statements to identify appropriate resolver. 
Or is there a better way to design this problem?

Comment: SO is it not a code review website. :) There are other forums for that. :)

Comment: You can simply register the resolvers against the factory and use an internal map to link a resolver with a request type.

Answer (score 0):

Following @plalx comment, here's an example:

```js
class ResolverFactory {
    private static readonly resolvers: Map<typeof DataRequest, DataResolver> = new Map([
        [FooDataRequest, new FooViewResolver()],
        [BarDataRequest, new BarViewResolver()]
    ]);

    public static getResolver(request: DataRequest): DataResolver {
        let resolver: DataResolver | undefined = ResolverFactory.resolvers.get(request.type);
        if (!resolver) {
            throw new Error(`Resolver for '${String(request.type)}' not found`);
        }
        return resolver;
    }
}
```